# Can't add TomCat sever in Eclipse using ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

So I installed tomcat using this tutorial (instructions from 0:00 to 3:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyd9EoO-1nk

Later I restarted my computer and now when I go into "eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Add" I have here only "Basic" and "GlassFish" directories. Somebody have maybe idea how to make visible tomcat here?

I also installed tomcat using "sudo apt-get install tomcat7" but it also didn't help. But when I go into "localhost:8080" I see "It works! If you're seeing this page via a web browser...".

Comment: Which version of eclipse have you installed? If you are doing servlet development then I'd definitely recommend "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" from the eclipse site. This has Tomcat adapters built in.

Answer (score 0):

**First part, the tomcat installation**

You installed tomcat in your linux as a service. I mean your tomcat 7 is installed, start when you start your OS, and stop when you stop your OS. 
You can check this by looking in /etc/init.d/, you must have a tomcat script (and you can control it by doing /etc/init.d/tomcat start|stop|restart). If you want to use this tomcat, I recommend you to

1. stop tomcat (as root, /etc/init.d/tomcat stop),
2. remove the tomcat script (as root, rm /etc/init.d/tomcat) to avoid a
   tomcat start when the ubuntu boots
3. Locate the tomcat instance installation. *find / -name tomcat
   -print* will print you all the directory where files named *tomcat* are located. Identify the tomcat root directory, which is the root
   to give to eclipse.

Else you can just remove tomcat (apt-get remove tomcat7), download a tomcat release from tomcat.apache.org and untar it where you want. I prefer this method, because the tomcat installation won't have any "root" o weird user permission, more convenient when you're developing.

**Second part, the eclipse configuration:**

In the "Add Runtime Environment" windows, you'd have a link Download additional server adapters. If you click it (with a working network connection), eclipse will propose you to download the tomcat adapter. Install it and you'll be capable to add a new tomcat server.

If it doesn't work, I think you may reinstall your eclipse...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't work :P But I redownloaded just eclipse and now it works. Propably I had wrong/old version of Eclipse.